# yarn: not found in deployer

Tags: ubuntu, yarnpkg, php-deployer

I installed the yarn by nvm.

```
root@server:~# which yarn
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v19.0.0/bin/yarn
```

It works when I login the machine and use `yarn` in terminal.

```
root@server:~# yarn -v
1.22.19
```

But once I try to run `yarn` in [`deployer`](https://deployer.org/) task,

```php
task('deploy:yarn', function () {
    run('cd {{release_path}} && yarn install', ['timeout' => 600]);
});
```

> The command "cd /var/www/my-web-project/releases/1 && yarn install" failed.
> Exit Code: 127 (Command not found)
> Host Name: example.com
> bash: line 1: yarn: command not found

It will throw out error: `yarn: command not found`

---

I try to run the `yarn` in a shell bash via a [`deployer`](https://deployer.org/) task

```php
task('deploy:upload-front-end-shell', function () {
    upload('build-front-end.sh', '{{release_path}}/build-front-end.sh');
});
```

**build-front-end.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

yarn && yarn build
```

or

```bash
alias yarn=$(which yarn)

yarn && yarn build
```

or

```bash
yarn_path=$(which yarn)

$yarn_path && $yarn_path build
```

None of those shell works via [`deployer`](https://deployer.org/) task, but works when I login the machine and run the shell manually.

---

How can I config my ubuntu20.04 to make `yarn` works in [`deployer`](https://deployer.org/) task?

Answer (score 0):

since yarn is installed in `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v19.0.0/bin/yarn` instead of `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, so it can't not be found by shell.

just create a soft-link can solve this:

```bash
ln -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v19.0.0/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn
chomd +x /usr/local/bin/yarn

# also for the node
ln -s /root/.nvm/versions/node/v19.0.0/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
chomd +x /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: Why didn't you add the `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v19.0.0/bin/yarn` to PATH?